# I need an after update trigger which gives me the updated column(s) name

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have two tables, first is the Employees table which has 100 columns like emp_id, name, age, dob, etc. The other is Employees_audit which as 3 columns emp_id, updated_column, updated_time. I need an after update trigger which gives me the updated emp_id and the updated column(s) name. Thanks in advance.

Sample data:

```
Table Employees:
----------
Emp_id|name|age|dob|....
1       abc  29  1991-10-28

Table Employees_audit
----------
Emp_id|updated_column|updated_time
```

---

Sample Output in Employees_audit:

```
Emp_id|updated_column|updated_time
1       dob            2017-10-27 8:40:57
```

Comment: What are you expecting for an answer here? We have nothing in the way of details here. With no information you are not likely going to get any solid response. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: That is decidedly not fun, certainly not if you want to do it efficiently. The tools at your disposal are [`COLUMNS_UPDATED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/columns-updated-transact-sql) and [`UPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql), but with 100 columns you probably want dynamic SQL to generate the trigger body (or even dynamic SQL in the trigger). Consider using [change data capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server) if it's available to you.

Comment: Accepted your answer, but change data capture is not available in the express edition

Answer (score 0):

the MyData table, where you want the trigger, needs a PK.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Audit](
[AuditID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Type] [char](1) NULL,
[TableName] [varchar](128) NULL,
[PrimaryKeyField] [varchar](1000) NULL,
[PrimaryKeyValue] [varchar](1000) NULL,
[FieldName] [varchar](128) NULL,
[OldValue] [varchar](max) NULL,
[NewValue] [varchar](max) NULL,
[UpdateDate] [datetime] NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
[UserName] [varchar](128) NULL,
[HostName] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTable_ChangeTracking] on [dbo].[MyTable] for insert, update, delete
as
SET NOCOUNT ON

declare @bit int ,
@field int ,
@maxfield int ,
@char int ,
@fieldname varchar(128) ,
@TableName varchar(128) ,
@PKCols varchar(1000) ,
@sql varchar(2000),
@UpdateDate varchar(21) ,
@UserName varchar(128) ,
@HostName varchar(100),
@Type char(1) ,
@PKFieldSelect varchar(1000),
@PKValueSelect varchar(1000)

select @TableName = 'MyTable'

-- date and user
select @UserName = system_user , @HostName = Host_Name(), 
@UpdateDate = convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 112) + ' ' + convert(varchar(12), getdate(), 114)
-- Action
if exists (select * from inserted)
if exists (select * from deleted)
select @Type = 'U'
else
select @Type = 'I'
else
select @Type = 'D'
-- get list of columns
select * into #ins from inserted
select * into #del from deleted
-- Get primary key columns for full outer join
select @PKCols = coalesce(@PKCols + ' and', ' on') + ' i.[' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '] = d.[' + c.COLUMN_NAME+']'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
where pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
and CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
and c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
and c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME
-- Get primary key fields select for insert
select @PKFieldSelect = coalesce(@PKFieldSelect+'+','') + '''[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']'''
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
where pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
and CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
and c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
and c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME
select @PKValueSelect = coalesce(@PKValueSelect+'+','') + 'convert(varchar(100), coalesce(i.[' + COLUMN_NAME + '],d.[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']))'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
where pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
and CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
and c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
and c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME
if @PKCols is null
begin
raiserror('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName)
return
end
select @field = 0, @maxfield = max(ORDINAL_POSITION) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @TableName
while @field < @maxfield
begin
select @field = min(ORDINAL_POSITION) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @TableName and ORDINAL_POSITION > @field
select @bit = (@field - 1 )% 8 + 1
select @bit = power(2,@bit - 1)
select @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1
if substring(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @bit > 0 or @Type in ('I','D')
begin
select @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = @TableName and ORDINAL_POSITION = @field
select @sql = 'insert Audit (Type, TableName, PrimaryKeyField, PrimaryKeyValue, FieldName, OldValue, NewValue, UpdateDate, UserName, HostName)'
select @sql = @sql + ' select ''' + @Type + ''''
select @sql = @sql + ',''' + @TableName + ''''
select @sql = @sql + ',' + @PKFieldSelect
select @sql = @sql + ',' + @PKValueSelect
select @sql = @sql + ',''' + @fieldname + ''''
select @sql = @sql + ',convert(varchar(1000),d.[' + @fieldname + '])'
select @sql = @sql + ',convert(varchar(1000),i.[' + @fieldname + '])'
select @sql = @sql + ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
select @sql = @sql + ',''' + @UserName + ''''
select @sql = @sql + ',''' + @HostName + ''''
select @sql = @sql + ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
select @sql = @sql + @PKCols
select @sql = @sql + ' where i.[' + @fieldname + '] <> d.[' + @fieldname+']'
select @sql = @sql + ' or (i.[' + @fieldname + '] is null and d.[' + @fieldname + '] is not null)'
select @sql = @sql + ' or (i.[' + @fieldname + '] is not null and d.[' + @fieldname + '] is null)'
exec (@sql)
end
end

GO
```

Comment: Yes, there is a primary key constraint and it's emp_id. Thank you so much

Comment: did this work for you?  could you please accept my answer?  thx!